# htaccess remove some characters from url and redirect 301

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, nsregularexpression

I have migrate from old website to the new one and want to redirect 301 some URLs. Can any one help?
I want to redirect 301

```
mywebsite.com/weblog/post1/amp
```

to

```
   mywebsite.com/weblog/post1/
```

Also

```
mywebsite.com/weblog/post1/comment-1234
```

or

```
mywebsite.com/weblog/post1/comment-5678
```

to

```
mywebsite.com/weblog/post1/#comment-1234
```

or

```
mywebsite.com/weblog/post1/#comment-5678
```

Also want to redirect `mywebsite.com/weblog/page/2` or `mywebsite.com/weblog/page/3` to
`mywebsite.com/weblog/`

Also want to redirect `mywebsite.com/weblog/post1#!/ccomment-comment=281` to
`mywebsite.com/weblog/post1/`

Answer (score 0):

I could redirect some of my problems with this format

```
`mywebsite.com/weblog/post1/amp` to   `mywebsite.com/weblog/post1/`
```

old url: `^/(.*)\/amp`  new url  `/$1`

`mywebsite.com/weblog/post1/comment-1234` to `mywebsite.com/weblog/post1/`

old url `^/(.*)\/comment=*` to new url `/$1`

But I couldn't redirect this URL.

```
mywebsite.com/weblog/post1#!/ccomment-comment=281
```